# . Suppose gcd(a, m) = d and that m > 1. Consider the congruence ax ≡ b (mod m). Should there be a solution for every choice of b?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function, euler-mascheroni-constant

If yes, prove your claim; if not, give a counter example

X is not told so I assume it can be any orbitrary number.  b is also abitrary, with that being said, isn't true due to those 2 factors?

Comment: $x$ is an unknown. $ax\equiv b$ is an equation, which may or may not have solutions. What the question is asking is whether the exact value of $b$ affects whether the equation has solutions..

Comment: 1) It's always a good idea to put the question in the text, not just in the title. 2) Are you sure that $m>1$ is given, $d>1$ would make much more sense here?

Answer (score 2):

No, it has not. For instance, the congruence $\;8x\equiv 5\pmod{12}$ has no solution, because it would imply that $5$ is divisible by $4$.

What can be said is this:

> The congruence $\;ax\equiv b\pmod m$ has a solution if and only if $b\equiv 0\mod d=\gcd(a,m)$.
>
> In this case, the congruence is equivalent to
> $$\frac ad\, x\equiv\frac bd\mod\frac md. $$